# Why wont Windows 10 Pro shut down with the ACPI power button when screen is locked locally?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, shutdown, linux-kvm, acpi

We have Windows 10 running under [KVM](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page) but it won't shut down when it gets an ACPI power button request triggered by `virsh shutdown win10` after a user locks the console---however, it *will* under the following conditions:

- No user is logged in
- User is logged in, screen is not locked
- User is logged in via Remote Desktop and console is locked because of the remote session.

Here is the question: How do we make it shut down under all circumstances (in this case when the local console is locked by a local user, not by RDP)?

We tried setting  `Local Group Policy Editor->Computer Config->Windows Settings->Security Settings->Local Policy->User Right Assignment->Shut down the system` for allowing ".\ANONYMOUS LOGON" but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We never got this working directly.  Instead we installed the [Windows SSH Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse) and the [Linux UPS server](https://networkupstools.org/) that needs to shut down the VM ssh's to the windows console and uses [rwinsta](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rwinsta) to reset the console session before shutting down the VM.